# Wp Super cache - Problemas na Home

Tags: wordpress

Alguem poderia me explica como se usa esse plugin corretamente?

Eu instalei e ativei  porem a home do site está esvaziando o cache muito rápido.

Explico.  nas paginas, posts, etc o cache é feito e não expira. vejo isso  pq quando acesso o codigo fonte  la no rodape tem a marca do tempo que foi criado. e mesmo atualizando o tempo não altera.

Agora na home do site as mesmas marcas são adicionada, mas o tempo que foi criado o cache altera constatemente,  ou seja toda vez que é acessado a home um novo cache é realizado ele não guarda por um tempo de expiração.

Já nas páginas e post o cache trabalha normalmente e leva um tempo determinado que eu adicionei nas configurações para ele expira.

Alguem ai sabe onde eu configuro para a home não esvazia o cache tão rápido?

Quando eu faço o teste eu sempre uso o modo anonimo do navegador.

Comment: Já experimentas-te visitar a página sem estares 'logado' e ver se o cache altera?

Comment: Sim eu uso o modo anonimo para verifica o cache das paginas, apenas a home não está segurando o cache e está expirando sempre que é acessada fazendo assim um novo cache

Comment: Qual o modo de _cache_ está utilizando?